# What ESA video contains this "family portrait" of comet-visiting spacecraft?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-art, esa

I don't use (or condone) FaceBook, but nonetheless I stumbled upon this page from a search:  https://www.facebook.com/ISEE3Reboot/photos/a.801544933207256.1073741827.800538433307906/1384594101569000/?type=3

It shows several cute satellites that are purported to have visited comets, or at least were supposed to do so. It appears to be a screenshot from an ESA video.

Any idea what that video might be? A link to it or it's ESA page would be greatly appreciated!

So far I've found one of these cuties in this [ESA video](https://youtu.be/vcYo-qQ5HbA) linked in this [ESA tweet](https://twitter.com/ESA_Rosetta/status/781827468407795712), but still looking for this "family portrait":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artwork strongly reminds me of the Rosetta mission. So, check out ESA's videos of/on the Rosetta mission.

**update:** Per @Hobbes' [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28340/what-esa-video-contains-this-family-portrait-of-comet-visiting-spacecraft#comment85409_28342), this family portrait is from a series of cartoons ESA commissioned as part of the Rosetta mission. The family portrait appears in '[Once upon a time, Rosetta's grand finale](http://www.esa.int/spaceinvideos/Videos/2016/09/Once_upon_a_time_Rosetta_s_grand_finale)' at `03:27`.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be left as a comment, because this is the correct answer. This family portrait is from a series of cartoons ESA commissioned as part of the Rosetta mission. The family portrait appears in 'Once upon a time, Rosetta's grand finale at 3:27. http://www.esa.int/spaceinvideos/Videos/2016/09/Once_upon_a_time_Rosetta_s_grand_finale

Answer (score 1):

The frame you show appears at timestamp 22:00 of the complete "The amazing adventures of Rosetta and Philae" compilation video.

A similar "family portrait" also appears around timestamp 11:30 of the same video.

The video can also be found on the ESA website, here:
https://m.esa.int/spaceinvideos/Videos/2016/12/The_amazing_adventures_of_Rosetta_and_Philae

Comment: Thanks for finding the complete version. With comparable answers I tend to accept the one from the newest or lower-rep user.